# How to send and receive array value by ajax.api using classic asp

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I want to send array value by ajax and receive but in ajax URL page's it get none value I want to know how to send and receive, please.

in ajax send page's

```
$('#Available').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"../clientlist/commisstion_api.asp",
                data:{id_tb:id_tb},
                    global:false,
                    success:function(data){
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    },
                    error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(thrownError); 
                    }
            });
        });
```

in receive page's

```
Ltbf1 = request("id_tb")
response.write "Ltbf1"&Ltbf1
```

[this is my header variable send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnqNn.png)

but in receive page's cant get value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
Ltbf1 = request("id_tb[]")
```

I hope it works!!!

Comment: hi, story ks it works!! thank you so much [thank you][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGJBy.png